# Vaadin, SpringBoot and Jersey get request returns 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, vaadin

it is my first post here, till now I finally always found the solution for my dev problem, but now I am really exchausted. Maybe you can help me.
I am trying to setup simple Rest get web app basing on vaadin + spring boot +
maven on tomcat. In some combinations in .pom i received the get response : "sth else" but in such case the vaadin ui wasnt loaded. In such configuration I paste below I cannot obtain the get response:

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.drzinks</groupId>
    <artifactId>site</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Site</name>
    <description>CRUD Vaadin Spring App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>7.7.3</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.3</vaadin.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- in order to have hot deploy in tomcat -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.7.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

web.xml:

```
    <web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Servlet declaration can be omitted in which case
         it would be automatically added by Jersey -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

WelcomeController.java:

```
    package com.drzinks;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/sth")
public class WelcomeController {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getSthElse(){
        return "sth elese";
    }
}
```

SiteApplication:

```
   package com.drzinks;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SiteApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

SiteUI.java:

```
    package com.drzinks;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SpringUI
@Theme("valo")
public class SiteUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    private RestClient restClient;

    private VerticalLayout layout;


    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setupLayout();
        addHeader();

    }


    private void setupLayout() {
        layout = new VerticalLayout(); //alt shift l extr local var
        setContent(layout);

    }

    private void addHeader() {
//      Label label1 = new Label(welcomeController.returnSth());
//      layout.addComponent(label1);        
        Label label2 = new Label(restClient.getSthFromServer());
//      Label label2 = new Label("restClient.getSthFromServer()");
        layout.addComponent(label2);
    }

}
```

RestClient.java:

```
   package com.drzinks;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.UIScope;

@UIScope
@Component
public class RestClient {

    private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    private WebTarget webtarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080");

    public String getSthFromServer() {
        String response;
        response = webtarget.path("sth")
                .request().get(String.class);
        return response;

    }

}
```

[folder_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBHZU.png)

If anyone could help, I would be very appreciated as I spent on this more than 12 hrs, breaking all night..